# Creating a Bullet at Character location

Tags: python, pygame

for about 3 hours I have been trying to create a bullet that will go in a specific direction from the characters location. I am attempting to get it to move away from the character with the variable BX, which is used here:

```
gameDisplay.blit(Eball,(BX + 25, y))
```

Although I know what I want to do, The best I have gotten is the bullet to appear without crashing the program, but it does not move forward, as it stays exactly 25 pixels away from the character. To time the bullet movement, i have tried using a while statement saying that as long as said variable [ e ] is under 20, run this code. every loop of game_loop() adds 1 to [ e ].

```
while e < 20 :
    e = e + 1
```

[ e ] Resets to 0 on every keydown attempting to use the bullet function [ energyBall ], as well as setting a direction for the bullet to True, as seen here.

```
elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
            e = 0
            right = True
            energyBall()

if (right == True):
        gameDisplay.blit(Eball,(BX + 25, y))
        pygame.display.update()
```

The full code can be seen here for context ( Thanks for helping me out ):

```
import pygame
import random
import time
import math
import cmath
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)


width=800
height=750

global x
x = 0
global y
y = 0
global e
e = 0
global x_move
x_move = 0

global y_move
y_move = 0

global enemyintx
enemyintx = random.randint(0,36)
global enemyinty
enemyinty = random.randint(0,24)
global enemyint2x
enemyint2x = random.randint(0,36)
global enemyint2y
enemyint2y = random.randint(0,24)
global enemy_x
enemy_x = 500
global enemy_y
enemy_y = 500
global enemy2_x
enemy2_x = 500
global enemy2_y
enemy2_y = 500


global right
right = False
global left
left = False
global up
up = False
global down
down = False 

global doorlocx
doorlocx = 0
global doorlocy
doorlocy = 0
global door_x
door_x = 0
global door_y
door_y = 0





black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)
blue = (0,0,255)


pygame.init()
gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Encounterer V1.0')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

plr = pygame.image.load('player.png')
door = pygame.image.load('door.png')
enemy = pygame.image.load('enemy.png')
enemy2 = pygame.image.load('enemy.png')
enemyfight = pygame.image.load('enemyfight.png')
grid = pygame.image.load('backgroundgrid.png')

GUI = pygame.image.load('GUI.png')
attbut = pygame.image.load('attbutton.png')
attbut2 = pygame.image.load('attbutton2.png')
potbut = pygame.image.load('potbutton.png')
potbut2 = pygame.image.load('potbutton2.png')
spebut = pygame.image.load('spebutton.png')
spebut2 = pygame.image.load('spebutton2.png')

Eball = pygame.image.load('energyball.png')

FBG = pygame.image.load('fightBG.png')
base = pygame.image.load('sphere.png')
cover = pygame.image.load('cover.png')

global doorintx
doorintx = random.randint(1,31)
global doorinty
doorinty = random.randint(1,23)




def door_round():
    global doorlocx
    global doorlocy


    doorlocx = doorintx * 25
    doorlocy = doorinty * 25


def enemy_round():
    global enemy_x
    global enemy_y
    global enemy2_x
    global enemy2_y

    enemy_x = enemyintx * 25
    enemy_y = enemyinty * 25

    enemy2_x = enemyint2x * 25
    enemy2_y = enemyint2y * 25


def enemy_move():
    global enemy_x
    global enemy_y
    global move_chance

    move_chance = random.randint(0,12)

    if enemy_x > 775: 
        enemy_x = enemy_x - 25

    if enemy_x < 25:
        enemy_x = enemy_x + 25

    if enemy_y > 575:
        enemy_y = enemy_y - 25

    if enemy_y < 25:
        enemy_y = enemy_y +25

    if (move_chance == 0):
        enemy_x = enemy_x + 25

    elif (move_chance == 1):
        enemy_x = enemy_x - 25

    elif (move_chance == 2):
        enemy_y = enemy_y + 25

    elif (move_chance == 3):
        enemy_y = enemy_y - 25

def enemy2_move():
    global enemy2_x
    global enemy2_y
    global move_chance2

    move_chance2 = random.randint(0,12)

    if enemy2_x > 775: 
        enemy2_x = enemy2_x - 25

    if enemy2_x < 25:
        enemy2_x = enemy2_x + 25

    if enemy2_y > 575:
        enemy2_y = enemy2_y - 25

    if enemy2_y < 25:
        enemy2_y = enemy2_y +25

    if (move_chance2 == 0):
        enemy2_x = enemy2_x + 25

    elif (move_chance2 == 1):
        enemy2_x = enemy2_x - 25

    elif (move_chance2 == 2):
        enemy2_y = enemy2_y + 25

    elif (move_chance2 == 3):
        enemy2_y = enemy2_y - 25





def player(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(plr,(x,y))

def energyBall(self):
    global e
    global right
    global left
    global down
    global up
    global x
    global y
    global BX
    global BY

    while e < 20 :
        e = e + 1
        if (right == True):
            gameDisplay.blit(Eball,(BX + 25, y))
            pygame.display.update()

        elif (left == True):
            gameDisplay.blit(Eball,(BX - 25, y))
            pygame.display.update()



        elif (down == True):
            gameDisplay.blit(Eball,(x, BY + 25))
            pygame.display.update()


        elif (up == True):
            gameDisplay.blit(Eball,(x, BY - 25))
            pygame.display.update()
        main_loop() 
        energyBall()





def mouseloc():
    mouse = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    if 13+99 > mouse[0] > 13 and 613 + 19 > mouse[1] > 613:
        gameDisplay.blit(attbut2,(13,613))

    elif 121+99 > mouse[0] > 121 and 613 + 19 > mouse[1] > 613:
        gameDisplay.blit(potbut2,(121,613))

    elif 229+99 > mouse[0] > 121 and 613 + 19 > mouse[1] > 613:
        gameDisplay.blit(spebut2,(229,613))



def game_loop():
    door_round()
    enemy_round()
    enemy_move()
    enemy2_move()
    x_move = 0
    y_move = 0
    global x
    x = 50
    global y
    y = 50


    crashed = False

    while not crashed:
        global e

        e = e + 1
        print(e)
        global BX
        BX = x
        global BY
        BY = y
        global doorlocx
        global doorlocy
        global enemy_x
        global enemy_y
        global enemy2_x
        global enemy2_y
        global right
        global left
        global down
        global up



        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                crashed = True

        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                x_move = -25

            elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_move = 25

            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_move = 25

            elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                y_move = -25


            elif event.key == pygame.K_d:
                e = 0
                right = True
                energyBall()

            elif event.key == pygame.K_a:
                e = 0
                left = True
                energyBall()

            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                e = 0
                down = True
                energyBall()

            elif event.key == pygame.K_w:
                e = 0
                up = True
                energyBall()



        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                x_move = 0


            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                y_move = 0


        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_d or event.key == pygame.K_a:
                BX = x
                gameDisplay.blit(cover,(BX,BY))
                pygame.display.update()



            if event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                BY = y
                gameDisplay.blit(cover,(BX,BY))
                pygame.display.update()




        if x > width or x < 0:
            x = 0

        if y > 575 or y < 0:
            y = 0



        if x == doorlocx and y == doorlocy:

            global doorintx
            doorintx = random.randint(0,31)
            global doorinty
            doorinty = random.randint(0,23)

            global enemyintx
            enemyintx = random.randint(0,36)
            global enemyinty
            enemyinty = random.randint(0,24)
            global enemyint2x
            enemyint2x = random.randint(0,36)
            global enemyint2y
            enemyint2y = random.randint(0,24)

            enemy_x = enemyintx * 25
            enemy_y = enemyinty * 25

            enemy2_x = enemyint2x * 25
            enemy2_y = enemyint2y * 25

            doorlocx = doorintx * 25
            doorlocy = doorinty * 25

        if x == enemy_x and y == enemy_y or x == enemy2_x and y == enemy2_y :
            print(" CONTACT ")
            fight()


        x += x_move
        y += y_move
        enemy_move()
        enemy2_move()
        gameDisplay.fill(black)
        gameDisplay.blit(grid,(0,0))

        gameDisplay.blit(GUI,(0,600))
        gameDisplay.blit(attbut,(13,613))
        gameDisplay.blit(potbut,(121,613))
        gameDisplay.blit(spebut,(229,613))
        mouseloc()
        gameDisplay.blit(door,(doorlocx,doorlocy))
        gameDisplay.blit(enemy,(enemy_x,enemy_y))
        gameDisplay.blit(enemy2,(enemy2_x,enemy2_y))
        player(x,y)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(10)




game_loop()  
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Comment: The title isn't much appropriate, I would have insisted on the idea of making the bullet move rather than printing it at initial position, since it seems to be your issue.

Comment: Try refactoring the program to make it simpler (having that many globals is a code smell). May I also suggest that you post your code [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

I might be really dumb, but to me it seems you always give the same position at which displaying the ball.

Your variable, BX (or BY, for all that mater) is added 25 (or substracted) in what appears to be the printing function call, but you don't save the result.

You have something like :

```
while e < 20 :  # 20 iterations without any external code getting called ?
    e = e + 1
    if (right == True):  # When ball goes right.
        gameDisplay.blit(Eball,(BX + 25, y))  # Display ball at current location + 25
        pygame.display.update()  # Now we display, BX isn't worth the same anymore.

    elif (left == True):
        gameDisplay.blit(Eball,(BX - 25, y))
        pygame.display.update()
```

What you might want to do would be :

```
while e < 20 :  # 20 iterations without any external code getting called ?
    e = e + 1
    if (right == True):  # When ball goes right.
        BX += 25  # BX gets augmented.
        gameDisplay.blit(Eball,(BX, y))  # Display ball at current augmented location.
        pygame.display.update()  # Now we display, BX is still worth the initial BX.

    elif (left == True):
        BX -= 25  # Left means bx needs to be lowered
        gameDisplay.blit(Eball,(BX, y)) # Display ball at current lowered location.
        pygame.display.update()
```

Etc, everywhere in your code. 
Also, peeps would say it's no good to have so many variables that are global though it doesn,t do much in python, but you could try using some more class, like a class for Energy Balls could be nice.

Edit Something like (probably not pep8 compliant):

```
class EnergyBall(object):
    def __init__(self, initx, inity, speed, image, gdf):
        self.P = [initx, inity]
        self.v = speed
        self.image = image
        self.display = gdf  # The function in the module you see to be using.

    def frame(self, orientation, axis):
        """
        Orientation should be a 1 or -1 valued integer.
        Axis 0 = x, 1 = y
        returns new ball position for collision check or something.
        """
        # Set new position given speed, axis and orientation.
        self.P[axis] += self.v * orientation

        # Set the display using the function passed as parameter earlier.
        self.display(self.image, self.P[0], self.P[1])
        return self.P
```

I'll let you figure out how to use something like that though, as if might vary depending on your implementation. Passing the handle of the display module function is a great tip to allow objects to deal with themselves. (Last parameter) ;)

*Note: I don't have python on this machine and the code I did could be completely br0ken. (Or partially) (or not fitting your python implementation)*

*PS: Though it definitely is just an opinion of mine, I definitely recommend you to try another language than python for starting programmation. It gives you the possibility to quickly try lots of thing, but you end up doing try-retry and sometime forgetting to remove unworking solutions to get back to initial state. (Just one possible issue, I'm not getting started on how doing try-retry programmation is wrong in itself.)*

What this means for your current situation is that you need to do some serious cleaning of your code. You added function calls that have no reasons to exist and such.

If you really want to do programmation using this prototyping approach, I would recommend you use a version control system like Git (https://git-scm.com/) to easily get access to what your code looked like in a previous version as well as sharing it easily with people who would help you.

Right now, you could go to after the first hour of your work, apply the simple patch I mentionned, and it would work. Here you are hiting on stuff you put in your code yourself earlier and forgot to remove (the loop, the call to main_loop and recursive call to EnergyBall, for example).

Comment: Note that it is all based on the assumptions I made about the module you are using, which I didn't know but assumed it was simply using  `blit` to save image/locations to be updated on `update` call.

Comment: Thanks, Let me try this out.

Comment: Were you trying the program or testing the code out of nowhere just to see if it works ? 

If you haven't instancied anything and then use for instance, my ball object which use a reference to the gameDisplay object, it might be an issue. 

Though doing that doesn't seem possible to me.

Comment: Also giving the line on which exceptions are thrown could be a good habit to take. ;)

Comment: Trying the program. I am observing what you did and implementing that into my code to see if it is successful. of course, its not word for word.

Comment: If you put the class there, try not using it at first. 

Just change all line with the + or - 25 for the corresponding in your base program. It should work if the earlier version was working.

Comment: Edited the class anyway, it was containing a dumb mistake. 
You should make ennemy class too. :3

Comment: I have spent 5 flipping hours on this today. This singular thing has taken me more time than it took to write the rest of the code. I am done for today, as I literally want to shove my face though my monitor. At the moment not only is it not moving forward, It is only appearing for a frame. as i have been entirely unsuccessful with looping it for and x amount of loops, I really can't get it to work. Kill me. All I need to know how to do is loop it without getting a crash because of it. I am running the mainloop() inside of it as well, So they should alternate.

Comment: So what you have right now is PERFECT and means your code is working.
What you might want to do now is get the 20-iteration loop out of the EnergyBall code. It's something you said you tried, but since you call EnergyBall every "game Turn", it means your ball will goes up 20 * 25 pixels. 

Tends to get out of map quickly enough I guess.

Comment: Ok, I will try this in the morning. Thank you for sticking with me and trying to help. I have only been doing python for 3 weeks and have learned off of online tutorials

Comment: Yeah, I had started doubting that and edited my answer, adding a comment on how to fix your current issues (the program works, the only bugs right now are the "patches" you tried and didn't remove) and a personnal opinion on that. 

Have a good night, no problem m8. :3